# Reference Error: PDFViewer is not defined

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

The following javascript code produces the error "PDFViewer is not defined".

```
var pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({ 
    container: container,
    viewer: viewer
});
```

In the html head section, above the pdfViewer code, I add the reference to it like this:

```
<script type="module" src="./pdf.js/web/pdf_viewer.js"></script>
```

In pdf_viewer.js, there is an export statement:

```
class PDFViewer extends BaseViewer {
...
}

export {
  PDFViewer
};
```

I'm not real familiar with imports, exports, modules, etc. so hoping one of you javascript experts can enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong.

----------------------------------------- Edit -------------------------------------------

Apparently the browser is not loading pdf_viewer.js.  Don't know why since the file is there.  The above code is an attempt to avoid a different error that occurs when loading the original version like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/pdf_viewer.js"></script>
```

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/pdf_viewer.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Put a console.log in the JS file above the class, and one before your instantiation, to see if 1) it loads at all, 2) it runs before your instantiation.

Comment: Also, what browser/version are you using? A module is ES6, so wont run in older versions of IE and Edge. Edge 16 is the earliest that will support `type="module"`.

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome browser.  I believe you are correct that it is not being loaded because status in Network tab showed "pending".  I'm going to update my post with more info.